# SKEffectNode with texture animation not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skaction, skeffectnode

Try this:

1. Create a SKEffectNode class
2. Create a small animation, 8 frames or so, put them into an atlas folder
3. add this code to the class init

**INIT CLASS**

```
-(id)init {

  self = [super init];

  if (self) {

    SKTextureAtlas *atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"shield.atlas"];

    NSMutableArray *images=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8];
    for (int i=1; i<=8; i++) {
      NSString *fileName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"shield%d.png",i];
      SKTexture *tempTexture=[atlas textureNamed:fileName];
      [images addObject:tempTexture];
    }

    NSUInteger numberOfFrames = [images count];

    SKAction *animate = [SKAction animateWithTextures:images timePerFrame:1.0f/numberOfFrames resize:YES restore:NO];
    SKAction *forever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:animate];
    [self runAction:forever];

  }

  return self;

}
```

Add this node to your scene. The result is nothing is rendered. Notice that I am not even enabling the effects yet.

why?

Comment: Have you added this node to the scene ?

Comment: It's not a SKSpriteNode. It's not obvious that you have added anything to the SKScene. What you need to do is add a SKSpriteNode property that utilizes your animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SKEffectNode` is not a `SKSpriteNode`, so you cannot utilize `SKSpriteNode`'s methods.  What you can do is create a `SKSpriteNode` property that utilizes your animation and add that as a child of your `SKEffectNode`.